# How to make Behaviors contain other Behaviors in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

It appears that everyone is doing a computer game with reactive-banana FRP framework, so I had to try that too. However, I'm stuck with the early steps, trying to describe the game data as reactive-banana `Behavior` types.

Basically, I'm trying to have a (changing) list of game characters (such as Frodo or Sam). The game characters might be updated on every game tick (modeled as a tick event). The idea is that whenever a game character is changed, a single `Event (Character)` is triggered, and the character update is finally sent over the network. The benefit of this compared to the [Asteroids.hs](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Asteroids.hs) example should be that the whole game state (the whole list of game characters) doesn't need to be sent over the network, since there will be a number of events having a single game character instead of a single event with a game character list.

For a single game character this works fine! I created the `Behavior (Character)` with `mapaccum`, so that the character update signal gets sent when the character is updated. The problem I can't solve is how to make this work with a `Behavior` list of game characters.

I'm trying to model the game character list as a `Behavior`, since characters might come and go during the game. Do I need to use dynamic event switching here? Or if I don't use `Behavior` with the individual game characters (and only use `Behavior` with the game character list), is there a way to conditionally trigger update events when I'm going through the character list? Or am I not understanding something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manage a dynamic collection of behaviors, you have to use dynamic event switching. See the [BarTab.hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#bartab) example for a demonstration.

However, dynamic event switching can be a bit unwieldy and it is often possible to avoid it. Two common situations are:

1. The collection of behaviors is known statically. The [TwoCounters.hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#twoCounters) demonstrates that one can simply use the applicative functor combinators to calculate a value depending on either behavior.
2. The dynamic collection can be modeled as a behavior of a collection (`Behavior [a]`) as opposed to a collection of behaviors (`[Behavior a]`). The [Asteroids.hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#asteroids) example demonstrates how to use this. This is a stylistic trade-off: the individual entries of the collection cannot be formulated with FRP anymore, but the collection becomes easier to manage.

Comment: All right, I was sort of thinking this might prove to be the case. I guess I'll try the "Behavior of a collection" way you mention and filter the non-changed characters out later.

Comment: In particular, I think I'll use the `spill` function for splitting the event that the character list is updated to several events for updating a single character.